# Sending Event Driven Push Notification Using Firebase Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a push notification to the Firebase Server using a POST request. I am successfully getting a 200 response as a result when using hurl.it. But I am unsure of how to implement a POST request with Body in Objective-C or Swift and I am looking for some guidance as my previous attempts for these requests have all thrown errors.

Also I am a little lost as to what my next steps are in order to implement Firebase push notification to devices (similar to this article for Android: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html)

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Here is the following information am I using to make the POST request to the Firebase Server:

```
 Type: POST
 URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
 Header: Content-Type: application/json
 Header: Authorization: key="my FCM token"
 Body: { 
 "priority": "high",
 "notification": {
 "title": "Houston vs. Oakland",
 "text": "+6"
 },
 "to" : "my FCM token"
 }
```

**Edit: Current code I am using, but the request doesn't seem to be going through. Could be the way I've structured my payload in the format of a NSDictionary..**

```
-(void)postToFirebase {

NSMutableDictionary *notifictionDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[notifictionDetails setObject:@"possesion" forKey:@"team 1"];
[notifictionDetails setObject:@"userid" forKey:@"id"];

NSMutableDictionary *sdetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[sdetails setObject:@"high" forKey:@"priority"];
[sdetails setObject:@"my FCM token" forKey:@"to"];
[sdetails setObject:notifictionDetails forKey:@"notification"];

NSLog(@"Required Format Data is %@",sdetails);

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sdetails];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSLog(@"Post Data Is: %@", postData);


NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue:@"key=" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSLog(@"The Request To Firebase: %@", request);

}
```

Comment: Do you want to send a notification that appears on the same device?

Comment: No I am trying to send notification based on events (i.e. possession changes, yards are accumulated, points scored). Trying to have this done all automatically. I already have remote notifications setup and working  with Firebase